# WampServer 3.1.9 64bit Not Showing The Correct PHP Version In Windows 10 Tray

Tags: windows-10, php, wamp

I have a perfectly working Wampserver 3.1.9 (64bit) running on a Windows 10 Pro desktop. It comes with PHP version 5.6.40 to 7.3.5. The problem I have is that when I switch to a different version of PHP, the tray will always say that it is running PHP version 7.3.5. The only way is for me to know what PHP version is currently running is to run phpinfo() on a webpage.

Anyone had this issue before and how can I resolve it so Wampserver will show the correct version. Thanks for any assistance in advanced.

Comment: I have the same problem, it's also not recognising new php versions that are installed (also running Win10/64bit

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check in httpd.conf file "php_module", whether correct version mapped in that, if not, change manually then restart apache, you get selected version in wamp. (check in phpinfo.php)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).